# mmenu: Click a menu item to expand?

Tags: jquery, mmenu

By default in [mmenu](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/), you have to click the arrow (to the right of the menu item) to show the submenu.

Is there a way to change it so that when you click anywhere on a menu item (doesn't have to be the arrow) it will expand as well?

My menu is roughly like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href='Page1.aspx'>Item with no submenu</a></li>
  <li><a>Click this to expand</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='sub1.aspx'>Submenu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href='sub2.aspx'>Submenu 2</a></li>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do this with using span tags ([as seen here in the right menu on one of their demos](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/mmenu/demo/advanced.html)). Give this a try:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href='Page1.aspx'>Item with no submenu</a></li>
    <li>
        <span>Click this to expand</span>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='sub1.aspx'>Submenu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href='sub2.aspx'>Submenu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

(You were also missing a closing  on your nested unordered list.

Answer (score 1):

Span does work but you have to use `<span></span>` INSTEAD of `<a href></a>`:

```
<li><span>About us</span>
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#about/history">History</a></li>
   <li><a href="#about/address">Our address</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

it won't work by adding span. You have to handle it via events