# jquery mmenu item to open submenu on click instead of being link?

Tags: jquery, mmenu

I had problem that mmenu seems according to tutorial to assume that all menu items are link.

I wanted mmenu to open submenu on click instead of behaving like a link (as in mmenu tutorial).

Answer (score 3):

It took me 20 minutes to find it:
https://github.com/BeSite/jQuery.mmenu/issues/45

For me, it was enough to use SPAN instead of A for main menu items.

Hope this is helpful for others, since I coudn't find the answer on stackoverflow.

EDIT: found related question on stackoverflow after creating this:

[mmenu: Click a menu item to expand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22703259/mmenu-click-a-menu-item-to-expand)

Comment: It took me 2 hours to tell myself that I should check on stackoverflow :) Thanks for the answer!